# custom backend tab in customer details with custom link to my custom controller

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs

i have create a module added a tab in customer detail page by using layout, here is the block at

app\code\local\Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\Action.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Adminhtml customer action tab
 *
 */
class Namespace_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Action
 extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template
    implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('customertab/action.phtml');

    }

    public function getCustomtabInfo(){

        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        $customtab='My Custom tab Action Contents Here';
        return $customtab;
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab label
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return $this->__('Action Center');
    }

    /**
     * Return Tab title
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return $this->__('Action Tab');
    }

    /**
     * Can show tab in tabs
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        $customer = Mage::registry('current_customer');
        return (bool)$customer->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Tab is hidden
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        return false;
    }

     /**
     * Defines after which tab, this tab should be rendered
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAfter()
    {
        return 'tags';
    }


}
?>
```

the tab is added with link http://localhost/m1/index.php/admin/customer/edit/id/135/key/ad3a6475755fae42cfe5eb9f0a616e09/#

it is possible to change this link to

```
http://localhost/m1/index.php/admin/custom/index/key/3ef15c673b708250e0eff44c716d5a96/
```

----update----

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\customertab.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
         <reference name="customer_edit_tabs">
            <action method="addTab">
                <name>customer_edit_tab_action</name>
                <block>customertab/adminhtml_customer_edit_tab_action</block>
                <url>admin/custom</url>
            </action>
        </reference>
   </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually add the tab to the collection of tabs for the customer edit?

Comment: @brett i use the layout about which included in config.xml

Comment: public function getTabUrl()  seems work for me

Comment: Glad you found the answer.  Since there were multiple ways to add a tab, I didn't want to lead you down a different route if you were but one step away.